# Node JS and Python - POST image from Node JS to Python REST API

Tags: python, node.js, image, rest, post

I have a Node JS application. I want to send an image from the Node JS application to a REST API which is written in Python. The key and the inputs needed by the Python REST API are as follows[image: 'Image' is the key which the Python API expects]

My problem is that I am able to POST a simple 'Hello World' string with the code I have written and get a response. However, when I try to send an image something goes wrong and I get no response.

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');

// This is some dummy string data
var postData = querystring.stringify({
    msg: 'hello world'
});


var fs = require('fs')
    , path = require('path')
    , certFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl/client.crt')
    , keyFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl/client.key')
    , caFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl/ca.cert.pem')
    , request = require('request');


// I want to send an image from one server to another. What changes should I make to the options below for POSTing image data
var options = {
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8888,
    path : '/predict',
    //image: fs.createReadStream('car.jpg'),  //Should I give something like this??
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Content-Length': postData.length
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    console.log('STATUS:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS:', JSON.stringify(res.headers));

    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY:', chunk);
    });

    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log('No more data in response.');
    });
});

req.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('Problem with request:', e.message);
});

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

Please let me know what changes I have to make to this code to post an image.I read about the use of `multer` package. However, the examples that I came across were using JS on both ends. Since for me, I have a Python REST API , I cannot use that. PLease help since I have been struggling with it for some time now.

Edit 1: Based on @Jana's suggestion, I added the multipart within the options and tried, where `image` is the key and the value is `fs.createReadStream('car.jpg')` . However, at the python end, it does not get the `'image'` key because of which I get a `False` response. What am I missing?

```
 var options = {
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8888,
    path : '/predict',
    //image: fs.createReadStream('car.jpg'),  //Should I give something like this??
    multipart: [
        {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
             body: JSON.stringify({'image': fs.createReadStream('car.jpg')          })
        }

    ],
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        //'Content-Length': postImageData.length
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
`request({
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/predict',
    multipart: [{
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "key": "value"
            })
        },
        {
            body: fs.createReadStream('car.jpg')
        }
    ],
},
function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        return console.error('upload failed:', error);
    }
    console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
})`
```

And also you can get the best examples from its own documentation [Request - Simplified HTTP client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Comment: I tried modifying the code to the above API, it gives a blank response. Also, could you tell me what should the "value" in nthe "key":"value " hold?

Comment: Actually, can you help me understand where I should put the 'image' key and what should be its corresponding value. That seems to be the issue. I put loggers in my python code and found that it is not able to get request.files.get('image') , hence the 'False' response.